Why can't I run my Hadoop job on Windows 10
I want to run my Hadoop job on my Windows 10, but I get UnsupportedOperationException
When I want to run my job with the following command:
hadoop jar job.jar org.hadoop.tutorial.WC_Runner

I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:492)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:136)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:173)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:950)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:245)

My Hadoop version:
Hadoop 3.4.0
Source code repository git@github.com:apache/hadoop.git -r bd8b77f398f626bb7791783192ee7a5dfaeec760
Compiled by root on 2024-03-04T06:35Z
Compiled on platform linux-x86_64
Compiled with protoc 3.21.12
From source with checksum f7fe694a3613358b38812ae9c31114e
This command was run using /C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.4.0.jar

openjdk version "1.8.0_412-412"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_412-412-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.412-b08, mixed mode)

Hadoop configs:
yarn-site.xml
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
    <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
  </property>

</configuration>

mapred-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
        <value>%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

core-site.xml
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000</value>
    </property>
  
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property><property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
</property><property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>

